# How to properly update RealmSwift pod on Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, realm, cocoapods

Last week I installed `RealmSwift` pod on my Xcode project, with version 3.2.0.

Yesterday, on Xcode logs, Realm encourage me to update to the last version, 3.3.0, so I ran the command `pod update RealmSwift` in order to update this pod.

Update process was smooth, but when I reopened the Xcode project and build the app, a new Warning was created:

```
/Pods/Realm/Realm/ObjectStore/src/sync/sync_session.cpp:544:17:
Enumeration value 'connect_timeout' not handled in switch
```

How can I solve this problem?

My apps are running correctly, but I don't know if this can be dangerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the update method you used, from the information you provided it seems the update went through perfectly fine. It seems the warning is generated by the source code of Realm. This doesn't mean that anything is wrong with your code, the issue lies in Realm's source code, which you cannot really change (unless you are willing to correct it yourself in a local copy or make a pull request to the repository on GitHub).

Since in most cases you don't want to correct any warnings related to 3rd party libraries when using CocoaPods to install them, I'd suggest turning off warnings for pods in your podfile.

You just need to add the `inhibit_all_warnings` line to your podfile right before you list the pods you use.